# How to check correctly if a div has the class to do something

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I use an if statement in jQuery to check if a div has the class "in"?

My code:

```
$("#short-top-nav-right a").click(function() {
    $(".collapse").one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
        if ($("div.collapse-site").hasClass("in")) {
            console.log("yes");
        } else {
            console.log("no");
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$('div').each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('in')){
        console.log("yes");
    }else{
        console.log("no");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jQuery's [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

```
$('div.collapse-site').each(function(index, element) {
    console.log('element at index ' + index + 'is ' + (this.tagName);

    console.log('hasClass? ' + $(this).hasClass('in')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
$("#short-top-nav-right a").click(function(){
    $(".collapse div.collapse-site").each(function(index,value){
     if ($(this).hasClass("in")) {
      console.log("yes");
     } else {
      console.log("no");
     }

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if **any** `div.collapse-site` also has the class `in`, simply:

```
if ($("div.collapse-site.in").length) {
    // Yes, at least one does
} else {
    // No, none do
}
```

...without any loop.

If you want to know, for **each** of the `div.collapse-site`, whether it has `in`, then `each`:

```
$("div.collapse-site").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("in")) {
        // Yes, this specific one does
    } else {
        // No, this specific one doesn't
    }
});
```